# Assistance with Singly Linked List (C++) program

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I've started learning linked lists in C++, and I've written a program to create and display a list. It compiles fine, but the execution fails.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
    public:
    int data;                       // information contained by the node
    node *next;                     // a pointer pointing to an instance of the class node.
};

class list
{
public:
    node *head;
    node *temp, *tp;
    void createlist();
    void displaylist();
};

void list :: createlist()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the list you want to create.\n";
    cin>>size;
    temp=head;
    for(int k=1;k<=size;k++)
    {
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new node[1];
        cout<<"Enter the data for node number 1\n";
        cin>>head->data;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {

            temp->next=new node[1];
            temp=temp->next;
            cout<<"Enter the data for node number \n"<<k;
            cin>>temp->data;
            temp->next=NULL;

    }
    }
}


void list::displaylist()
{
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"List is empty.";
    }
    else
    {
        while(tp!=NULL)
        {
        tp = head;
        cout<<tp->data;
        tp = tp->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
        list obj;
    cout<<"Creating list...\n";
    obj.createlist();
    cout<<"Displaying list...\n";
    obj.displaylist();
    return 0;
}


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
    public:
    int data;                       // information contained by the node
    node *next;                     // a pointer pointing to an instance of the class node.
};

class list
{
public:
    node *head;
    node *temp, *tp;
    void createlist();
    void displaylist();
};

void list::createlist()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the list you want to create.\n";
    cin>>size;
    temp=head;
    for(int k=1;k<=size;k++)
    {
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new node[1];
        cout<<"Enter the data for node number 1\n";
        cin>>head->data;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {

            temp->next=new node[1];
            temp=temp->next;
            cout<<"Enter the data for node number \n"<<k;
            cin>>temp->data;
            temp->next=NULL;

    }
    }
}


void list::displaylist()
{
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"List is empty.";
    }
    else
    {
        while(tp!=NULL)
        {
        tp = head;
        cout<<tp->data;
        tp = tp->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
        list obj;
    cout<<"Creating list...\n";
    obj.createlist();
    cout<<"Displaying list...\n";
    obj.displaylist();
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

`Creating list...
Enter the size of the list you want to create.
3
Enter the data for node number 1
1`

So, the data for the second node doesn't get accepted. I'm new to linked lists, and want to try solving the problem this way, and I've spent too much time on this. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: This is off-topic because SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to get your feet wet with a debugger. What IDE are you using?

Comment: So as a first action for solving this, start up your program in a debugger, step through line by line, and watch how variables change. This should give you a good impression what's actually going on.

Comment: You should learn what a debugger is and how to use one in finding bugs in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Data members head and tp were not initialized when object obj was created and have any arbitrary values. So the program has undefined behaviour. Also it is a bad idea to make temporary variables as tp or temp data members of the class. They have to be local variables of member functions where they are used.

There is no any sens to allocate an array of nodes as you are doing.

```
head = new node[1];
/...
temp->next=new node[1];
```

Write simply

```
head = new node();
/...
temp->next=new node();
```

Also it would be better to define class node as an internal class of class list.

And do not forget to write the destructor that to free the allocated memory.